# Need Help For Set Google Plus API in Grails

Tags: grails, oauth, google-plus

I am using Grails OAuth plugin.

Here is `Config.groovy` code:

```
oauth {
  providers {
    google {
        api = org.scribe.builder.api.GoogleApi
        key = 'XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        secret = 'XXX'
        scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
        callback = "${grails.serverURL}/oauth/google/callback"
        successUri = "${grails.serverURL}/login/google"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is `LoginController` code:

```
def google() {
    Token token = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('google')]
    def googleResource = oauthService.getGoogleResource(token,
               grailsApplication.config.grails.google.api.url)
    def googleResponse = JSON.parse(googleResource?.getBody())

    log.info "token = ${token}"
    log.info "googleResponse = ${googleResponse}"
    log.info "accesstoken = ${token.token}"
    log.info "id = ${googleResponse.id}"
    log.info "name = ${googleResponse.name}"
    //println googleResponse.name
    //render params
    redirect(controller: "Profile",action:"dashboard")

  }
```

And here is error

> 2015-04-22 14:10:55,902 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR
>   errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - OAuthException occurred when
>   processing request: [GET] /uxsurvey/oauth/google/authenticate -
>   parameters: redirectUrl:  Response body is incorrect. Can't extract
>   token and secret from this: 'Consumer is not registered:
>   455253656547-3vrklc5phr5shur4l97qhk56ej8o028v.apps.googleusercontent.com
>   '. Stacktrace follows: Message: Response body is incorrect. Can't
>   extract token and secret from this: 'Consumer is not registered:
>   455253656547-3vrklc5phr5shur4l97qhk56ej8o028v.apps.googleusercontent.com
>   '

Here is google Api client ID Code

```
 Client ID
XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address
XXX.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret
XXX
Redirect URIs

    http://localhost:8080/uxsurvey/login/google

Javascript Origins
none
```

Comment: Not sure on the answer, but If that's your actual secret key, I'd change it now you've posted it on the internet... ;-)

Comment: Thakn you for your suggestion

Comment: What is the value of `grailsApplication.config.grails.google.api.url`?

Comment: grails.google.api.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"

Answer (score 0):

All the code and configuration looks good to me. I am also using same code and my application working fine ([Grails OAuth Plugin Demo](http://grailsoauthplugindemo.herokuapp.com/)). May be your Client ID and Secret are wrong. May be [this blog post](http://jellyfishtechnologies.com/integration-with-google-using-grails-oauth-plugin/) helps you.